# accessing element in matrix based on a specific value

Tags: python, matrix, element

I have the following code, and need some suggestions as to how I could access a specific element in the matrix based on the number rolled by the dice. For instance, on game start, if the rolled number is 8, the matrix position would be 8. I'm not sure of the syntax particularly as I've used a slightly different approach to creating the matrix:

Matrix output below

```
[43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
[42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36]
[29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
[28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22]
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
[14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Note: If the user rolls 7, it would be assessing the 6th element in the first sublist, however if the user rolls 8, it would be the last element in the next sublist (as opposed to the first) due to the layout.

The code I have so far is as follows. The only bit I need some suggestions with is how to access and calculate the element in the matrix based on the dice rolled number:

```
    def RollTwoDiceP1(player1,player2):
    turn=input("Player 1, it's your turn to roll the dice: Press r to roll:>>>")
    #create two variables here and assign them random numbers
    die1=random.randint(1,6)
    die2=random.randint(1,6)
    #add the two die numbers together
    roll=die1+die2    
    #when you are printing an integer, you need to cast it into a string before you printit
    print("Player1: You rolled a:", die1, "and a", die2, "which gives you a:", roll)
    playing = False
    for i in matrix(7):
        #list=[i[0]]#this gives me the first column, or the first index in each sub list
        moves=roll
        print("You have moved", roll, "spaces to position:.......")#here I want to access the element in the list that corresponds to the number rolled. e.g. if 8 rolled, it would be on position, 8

    playerturns(player1,player2,playing)
```

The code that creates the grid/matrix and displays it is:

```
    def matrix(n): 
    grid = [[1 + i + n * j for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)] 
    for row in grid[1::2]:
        row.reverse()    
    return grid[::-1][:]

def callmatrix(player1,player2, n):
    print("*************LOADING GAME******************")
    print("Welcome:", player1,"and", player2)
    for i in matrix(n):
            print(i)
    playing = True
    playerturns(player1,player2,playing)
```

Comment: Note: I don't want to be using pandas, numpy or anything like that - so don't want any suggested solutions that make use of anything other than the very basic python tools / a fix to what's already been used

Comment: to clarify some stuff, the thing you're referring to as the first sublist is actually the last sublist. put all of those lists into a single list `l` in the order they're currently in and then do `l[-1]` and you'll see what i mean.

Comment: yes, thanks - but doesn't answer the question or make any suggestions?

Comment: Well, the order you're lists are in matters a great deal for how you're going to access elements in them. Since each of your lists is 7 items long, you can probably use division to find the quotient (that's your row) and the remainder (that's your element in the row). For eg: if you want the 8th item: 8/7 = 1 with a remainder of 1, that means you want the 1st element in the 2nd list, that make sense?